# Can we say : Steel of the bike is stainless? (I mean without "the" before "steel of the bike")

Tags: grammar

Can we say : Steel of the bike is stainless? (I mean without "the" before "steel of the bike")
and what about "Punch lines of the jokes are hilarious."and" Oases of the desert are large."(without "the" in the subjects)
note that  all the three expressions *Steel of the bike*,*Punch lines of the jokes*,and *Oases of the desert* involve the part-whole relation.
I expect  the intuitive judgements from native speakers. Thanks a lot to the answerers !!!

**P.S.** It's amazing to receive such a long and clear reply from Tᴚoɯɐuo. It's beyond my expectation. But in the sentence"Students of Southern Polytechnic were likewise concerned their school's identity would be lost and reputation hurt in the merger with Kennesaw State", the phrase "Students of Southern Polytechnic"  can be paraphrased as "the students of Southern Polytechnic", namely not unspecified as "some  students of Southern Polytechnic". Besides,if I paraphrase "Steel of the bike's frame is rusting in places" as  "The steel of the bike's frame is rusting in places" , have I kept the meaning of the former sentence? Finally, do you mean that one phrase like "Oases of that desert" is not allowed to mean"The oases of that desert" ?

Answer (score 3):

No, we cannot.

For your bike steel example, it's not appropropriate to express the idea in that way, in English. We wuold say, "The bike is stainless steel." (Or, less common: "The metal of the bike is stainless steel."). Either way, you must use "the," because you are 'pointing' with your words to a specific (determinate) object.

Similarly, we would more naturally say, "The jokes' punchlines are hilarious," and "The deserts' oases are large."

It is still grammatical but less natural to say, "The punchlines of the jokes are hilarious," and "The oases of the desert are large."

Comment: But strangely, the following sentences are allowed(i found them in COCA): a.Students of Southern Polytechnic were likewise concerned their school's identity would be lost and reputation hurt in the merger with Kennesaw State.
    b. Members of the Geneva marketing team were spread throughout the cabin
Here we are also pointing to specific objects.

Answer (score 0):

Setting your question about the article aside, it takes a special context to justify

> The steel of the bike is stainless.

which is grammatical but not idiomatic under most circumstances. Normally a native speaker would say

> The {thing} is stainless steel.
>
> The {thing} is made of stainless steel.
>
> This is a stainless steel {thing}.

If the thing is made of several different metals, you might say something like

> The roof of this building is made of aluminum, and the steel of the doors is stainless.

There, you are comparing or enumerating the different metals of the different pieces, which would justify the pattern you are asking about.

Let's say you were developing a specification for a building of some kind:

> Roofing materials must be non-flammable.
>
> In exterior application, steel should be stainless.

There, you could forego the article since you're referring to the *generic* material.

P.S. In a comment OP goes on to clarify:

> I did not make myself clear. Some expressions of the structure
>   NP+of+NP (with the denotations of the two NPs in the part-whole
>   relation) are allowed to have a definite reading without using “the”,
>   e.g. Students of Southern Polytechnic were likewise concerned their
>   school's identity would be lost(from COCA). i want to find out if
>   “steel of the bike”, “punch lines of the jokes” and “oases of the
>   desert” can have a definite reading without using “the".

The word *definite* is rather indefinite, but let's look at a few sentences.

`Without the definite article, NP1 (in`NP1 of NP2`constructions) will refer to the noun as generic or unspecified, defined only in terms of its association with, or its being a part of, or its being the essential fabric of NP2`.

**In front of the library, *students of the university* were protesting the firing of the Dean**.

Some unidentified, unspecified students who attend the university.

**I won't buy it. *Handle of the teacup* is broken off.**

No. Ungrammatical. When referring to a specific component of an assembly, we use "the":

The handle of the teacup is broken off.

**Restoring it would be quite a project. *Steel of the bike's frame* is rusting.**

That is marginal.  Unlike the handle of the teacup, steel is not a part of the frame; rather the frame is made from the material.  The sentence could be made less marginal if we add a phrase:

Steel of the bike's frame is rusting *in places*.

or refer to the steel *everywhere* on the frame:

The steel of the bike's frame is rusting.

**The comic was banned from daytime TV. *Punchlines of the jokes* were deemed inappropriate for daytime audiences.**

This sentence has two problems. "the jokes" is ungrammatical without either some prior reference to those jokes

... banned from daytime TV for telling off-color jokes.

or some further restriction upon the NP: "the jokes *he told*".

**The comic was banned from daytime TV. *Punchlines of the jokes he told* were deemed inappropriate for daytime audiences.**

That is OK. A determiner is unnecessary but possible there:

[The] punchlines of the jokes he told were deemed inappropriate...

Notice the plural there with **punchlines...jokes**.  The plural is what makes that example different from **handle of the teacup**. Some or many of his punchlines were inappropriate, a sufficient number, or more than a sufficient number, to get him banned from daytime TV.

**In places where there is water underground *oases of the desert* flourish.**

**oases of the desert** is a generic reference to a phenomenon, not to specific oases, except insofar as **of the desert** differentiates desert oases from other kinds of oases. But is there really any other kind, barring figurative ones?

Her class on Giotto was an oasis in a wasteland of art-theory.

P.P.S.

Whether **Students of Southern Polytechnic** means *all* or *some* can only be determined by context:

> Students of Southern Polytechnic were involved in the car-jacking.
>
> Students of Southern Polytechnic must take *Electrical Engineering 101*.

These sentences have equivalent meaning:

> Steel of the bike's frame is rusting in places.
>
> The steel of the bike's frame is rusting in places.

With respect to your final example, you have introduced the word **that**.

**Oases of that desert.**

Which can be quite different from

**Oases of the desert.**

In the latter, **the desert** can refer to *all* deserts (in which case **oases of the desert** can be paraphrased as *desert oases*) or it can refer to a specific *aforementioned* desert, the desert we have been speaking of.  With the latter, **that desert**, we are referring only to a particular desert.

"oases of the desert"  oases found in deserts the world over [unless **the** is  anaphor or cataphor]

"oases of that desert" refers to oases found in a particular desert only.

Comment: thank you. I did not make myself clear. Some expressions of the structure NP+of+NP (with the denotations of the two NPs in the part-whole relation) are allowed to have a definite reading without using “the”, e.g. Students of Southern Polytechnic were likewise concerned their school's identity would be lost(from COCA). i want to find out if “steel of the bike”, “punch lines of the jokes” and “oases of the desert” can have a definite reading without using “the".

Comment: See the P.S.   **of** is a complicated preposition.

Comment: Thanks. My reply to you has too many words to submit. See the p.s. in my question above.

Comment: OK. See my PPS.